# macro C++ #define EXAMPLE(obje) (::f(s, (obje), arg1, arg2, arg3))

Tags: c++, macros

I have this special macro  function in C++ :

Could you explain to me how that works :

```
#define EXAMPLE(obje) (::f(s, (obje), arg1, arg2, arg3))
```

I have several questions :

1) What does `::f` mean ? Where does the compiler search the function `f` ?

2) What does `(obje)` mean ? Why is it between parenthesis ?

Comment: `::f` means something named `f` in the global (unnamed) namespace.   As used in the macro, `::f` is (presumably, since you haven't shown anything about it) a function that accepts five arguments.    `obje` is an argument of the macro - for example, if the macro is used as `EXAMPLE(2)` the preprocessor turns it into `(::f(s, (2), arg1, arg2, arg3))`

Answer (score 8):

`::f(...)` - call funcion `f` searching only the global scope (avoiding argument depednent lookup). (assuming `f` is a function).

`(obje)` - `obje` with brackets round it. Depends on what `obje` is.  Typical macro trick to avoid `obje` having strange effects when the macro is expanded.

Comment: An example of a "strange effect" would be helpful. My example: `EXAMPLE(1, 2)`.

Comment: @Evg in this particular case I am not sure if there is one (unless `obje` when expanded could contain the `,` operator).  Macro expansion problems usually happen when expanding macros arguments into the middle of expressions and the macro argument is itself an expression.  You can then get problems with operator priority.  Just saw your updated comment.

Comment: @Evg `EXAMPLE(1, 2)` shouldn't compile at all, because the macro only has one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What does ::f mean ?

`::` is the scope resolution operator. `f` is presumaly an identifier. `::f` is a fully qualified name that refers to `f` that is in the global namespace.

> Where does the compiler search the function f ?

`f` is looked up in the global namespace.

> 2) What does (obje) mean ?

`obje` is a parameter of the function like macro. It will be replaced by the text that is passed as an argument.

> Why is it between parenthesis ?

The parentheses around macro parameters ensure that it is syntactically a single expression. In many macros, lack of parentheses around arguments can lead to unexpected results with some inputs.

I don't know if this macro could have problematic inputs without the parentheses, but conventionally using them is safer than guessing whether there might be a problem, and such convention is typically enforced by style checkers.